# Solr autocomplete on words not in beginning of string

Tags: solr

I have some docs in Solr that contains information about books. One of the fields is author, defined as:

`<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

This is an example of a doc:

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">db04</str>
    <str name="isbn">0596529325</str>
    <str name="author">Toby Segaran</str>
    <str name="category">Computers/Programming/Information Retrieval/Machine Learning</str>
    <arr name="title">
      <str>Programming Collective Intelligence</str>
    </arr>
    <int name="yearpub">2007</int>
    <date name="pubdate">2007-07-28T00:00:01Z</date>
    </doc>
```

I'm trying to create a autocomplete system using Solr 4.2. So far it worked well, if I search for `to` it returns me `Toby Segaran` as the result.

But in our website many people searches for `Segaran` for instance and I was wondering if is it possible to somehow suggest `Toby Segaran` when this happens.

So far this is the schema.xml I'm using:

```
<field name="author_suggest" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<copyField source="author" dest="author_suggest"/>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_auto">
  <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Basically the field `author` is processed and copied to `author_suggest`.

In solrconfig.xml, these were created:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="field">author_suggest</str> 
    <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">6</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

So is this possible to somehow make suggestions based on words that are not exactly at the beginning of the phrase using the suggester from Solr?

If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance